# Thousands of instances of index.php opening at the same time

Tags: wordpress, hosting, bbpress

Suddenly my hosting account has been suspended due to thousands of instances of index.php opening at the same time.

The site is built around the latest version of Wordpress and bbpress. here's the email from the hosting company:

> *Action Taken:  Please be aware we have suspended this account at this
>   time in order to maintain the
>   reliability and integrity of the
>   server. Reason:  Thousands of
>   instances of index.php opening at the
>   same time:

```
17270 myserver 15 0 268m 79m 52m R
17.5 2.0 0:00.38 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17287 myserver 16 0 268m 34m 8712 R
14.4 0.9 0:00.35 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17332 myserver 15 0 213m 26m 7680 S
12.9 0.7 0:00.17 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17276 myserver 16 0 283m 40m 7912 R
12.1 1.0 0:00.33 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17336 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
12.1 0.7 0:00.16 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17341 myserver 18 0 213m 26m 7680 S
12.1 0.7 0:00.16 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17343 myserver 16 0 213m 26m 7680 S
12.1 0.7 0:00.16 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17339 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17344 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17347 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17351 myserver 16 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17353 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17364 myserver 17 0 213m 26m 7680 S
11.4 0.7 0:00.15 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17368 myserver 17 0 209m 23m 7388 R
10.6 0.6 0:00.14 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php 17278 myserver 16 0 283m 40m 7896 R
9.9 1.0 0:00.28 /usr/bin/php /home/myserver/public_html/index.php*
```

They have just emailed this too:

*it is possible that your forum script is being abused if it is not secured or it has some security whole, but we can't provide more information as we do not know how it is coded.
Please check and let us know if you have any further questions.*

Any ideas at what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exactly what dav said or for some reason you are getting an insane load... to prevent that from happening again, you can cache your wordpress using a plugin like [supercache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) to create some semi static pages, filter spam comments pre-reload. Because every single page load = loading index.php.

Comment: Any idea what causes this? Wordpress bug or some malicious programmer someplace?

Comment: Ok, I've done some digging and it seems this is the problem. Is there a way to guard against this happening again?

Thanks Dav and Kasumi for your answers :)

Comment: you can't really guard against DoS or server overload... It's not a wordpress bug, it's the only way to serve dynamic content...

Caching will definitely help... so it shouldn't be a problem next time...  After that and you still have problems, it's pretty much your own server time =P...

Answer (score 1):

You may have gotten [DoS'd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with sites getting indexed all at once especially from crawlers like Yandex/Baidu who load up multiple pages at once

every page load via bot is another instance of index.php opening - so if you have 2000 pages on the site and they  get indexed all at once - this is what you get

You can try to add the below to your robox.txt (might or might not work)

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-Delay: 30
Disallow: /wp-admin/
User-agent: Yandex
Crawl-Delay: 30
User-agent: Baidu
Crawl-Delay: 30
```

or just block IP's of crawlers (100% guarantee)